# I can’t access my site from the phone after I deleted the domain from FirebaseHosting and deleted the prefix URL in Dynamic links

Tags: firebase, web, firebase-hosting, firebase-dynamic-links

[problem picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/07CXf.jpg)I added my own domain on FirebaseHosting to use Dynamic links in my application.
After I decided to remove it since it was not needed anymore ...
I deleted the domain with FirebaseHosting and deleted the prefix URL from DynamicLinks FIrebase, but after that, I couldn’t access my website from the phone, it goes fine on the laptop ...
although before adding to FirebaseHosting and DynamicLinks, the site could go from the phone.
Tell me what could be the problem?

Comment: Are you accessing the *hosted* site from your laptop (as in: not localhost)?

Comment: Hans Keﬆing 
Yes, on a laptop I can easily go to my site ... it works as always. just stopped opening via phone from FIrebase

Comment: Maybe your laptop remembered the DNS setting for your site. If so, the windows command `ipconfig /flushdns` should clear that

Comment: @HansKeﬆing 
it turns out the whole problem was solved by simply rebooting my phone) Thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by simply clearing the cache.